# How to add custom LCD characters to a string array

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd

Im trying to add custom letters to my "compliment box" project, so I can write complients in my own language, but I have no idea how to add the custom characters to the project and implement them in the string array.

This is my attempt at a program that prints a random compliment on the press of a button without printing the same compliment twice in a row.

I tried this:

```c
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);

const int BUTTON_PIN = 7;

int randNum = 0;
int previousRandNum = 0;

// Create custom letter
byte Ao[8] = {
  B00100,
  B01010,
  B00100,
  B01110,
  B00001,
  B01111,
  B10001,
  B01111
};

// Compliments Go Here
String compliments[] = {
  "Test 0 {Ao}",
  "Test 1",
  "Test 2",
  "Test 3",
  "Test 4",
  "Test 5",
  "Test 6",
  "Test 7",
  "Test 8",
  "Test 9",
};

void clearLCD() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("                    ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("                    ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("                    ");
}

// put your setup code here, to run once
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed (analogRead(A0));
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();

  // Create custom letter? I think
lcd.createChar(0, Ao);
  
  lcd.setCursor (0, 1);            // go to the top left corner
  lcd.print("  Dette er en boks  "); // write this string on the top row
  lcd.setCursor (0, 2);            // go to the 2nd row
  lcd.print("     Trykk  her     "); // pad string with spaces for centering
}

void loop() {
if (!digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN)) {
  randNum = random(0, 10);
  previousRandNum = randNum; // move random num to previous num to prevent same number twice in a row
  clearLCD();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(compliments[randNum]); // print a random compliment from the array
  Serial.println(randNum);
  delay (1000);
  }
if (previousRandNum == randNum) {
  randNum = random(0, 10);
  }
}
```

I searched around for `customChar` for a while, but still haven't found a way to add them, so I can use them in a sentence in the compliments string array. I realize that the `lcd.createChar` is after the string array, but I don't know what to do.

I would also love any comment on how I could tidy up the code, like how to order things and make it easier to read.

Comment: The eight custom characters you can defined are used via character codes 0 thru 7, or alternatively 8 thru 15.  Code 0 is a bit of a problem - you can't put that in a string literal, because it would be interpreted as the null character that ends the literal.  So use `\x08` in a string to produce the first custom character, and `\x01` through `\x07` for the rest of them.

Comment: Also, instead of making a custom function to clear the LCD, just use lcd.clear();